# Find the smallest subset of binary vectors that cover the largest amount of dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a set of binary vectors where each vector $\vec{p}_i$ represents a book, and each dimension of $\vec{p}_i$ represents a word $i \in D$ where $D$ is the set of all words in all of our books.

${\vec{p}_i}_j=1$ indicates that word $j$ is in book $i$, and ${\vec{p}_i}_j=0$ indicates it is not.

How can I find the smallest set of books that cover all words in $D$ within a given threshhold (e.g. 99%)?

Comment: This problem is equivalent to the “set cover problem.” You might find help using that term.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem https://www.google.com/search?q=threshold+set+cover+problem

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $n$ books and $p$ words. Define the $n \times p$ incidence matrix $(M)_{ij} = p_{ij}$ whose rows are the vectors $p_i$.

We may frame this problem as finding a [sparse approximate solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation) to the matrix equation $b = Mw$.

In particular, given a coverage threshold $t \in [0,1]$, we wish to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{w \in \{0,1\}^n} \|w\|_0 \textrm{ subject to } \frac{\|Mw\|_0}{p} \geq t,$$
where $\{0,1\}^n$ is the set of $n$-dimensional binary vectors and $\|w\|_0$ is the $l_0$ "norm" of $w$. The $l_0$ "norm" is just the number of nonzero entries; it in fact is not a norm, hence the quotes.

Take this with a grain of salt though, there may be an easier/canonical way to do it.